# N-gon's circumcircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, polygons

In a regular n-gon, the radius of the circumcircle is equal in length to the shortest diagonal. Find the total number of values of n<60 which this can happen.

The answer is n = 12 (only one value), which is convincing. However, could someone give a foolproof method for this problem? Is there any way to show that this solution is THE ONLY solution? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We end up with the following figure. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the shortest diagonal is one that skips over just one vertex. The central angle it subtends is $\alpha = 2 \cdot 2 \pi / n\,$, and its length is $2 R \sin \alpha/2\,$.

Comment: Perfect! Got it! Thanks